# Asking About Other Prove To Use In Solving This Inequality

Tags: inequality, muirhead-inequality, schur-inequality

Let $\  (x,y,z) \  $ be positive real numbers such that $\ \  (x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=8 \ \ $ Prove That
$x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3+x^2y^2z^2-4xyz>=0$

Muirhead Sols
First homogenize, by multiplying by $2$ and replacing the coefficient of $xyz$ with the condition.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{sym}x^3y^3+2x^2y^2z^2-(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)xyz&\ge0\\
\sum_{sym}x^3y^3+2x^2y^2z^2-\sum_{sym}x^3y^2z-2x^2y^2z^2&\ge0\\
\sum_{sym}x^3y^3&\ge\sum_{sym}x^3y^2z
\end{align*}
which follows by Muirhead.

is there any solution without Muirhead or schur

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @markvs I've tried using Schur already but I'm not sure enough to finish it

Comment: If you do not include details like what you try, the motivation, etc. in the question, it will most probably be closed. In addition, it will most probably be deleted together with all the answers, so people would not want to answer it.

Comment: Ok i will add that next time , I'm new here and also I already found the answer thank you for your advice @markvs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schur Solution

$x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3+3x^2y^2z^2\ge\sum_{sym}x^3y^2z.$
Then using this bound in the homogenized inequality we can simplify to
$\sum_{sym}x^3y^2z\ge6x^2y^2z^2$
which follows by AM-GM